# ClientError at /api/document/ An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm getting this error while I'm trying to upload a fil into s3, The following is my bucket policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowGetAndHead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::monover-052023-s3bucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-1684257818955",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::monover-052023-s3bucket/*"
    }
]
```

}

does this has any error that cause this error please help me to fix it I tried a couple of ways to fix but not working also does this can be occurred due to any code issue if so where might it get happens please share your thoughts also

Here is my setting.py where the connection is made, I double-checked the AWS credentials and also no issues find

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "AKIAZO7XJSQ54CWZNR6K"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "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"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "django-monover-textract"
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
```

Comment: I'm using Django where I can allow the operation can you explain it

Comment: Also while adding the HeadObject to the policy I get the following error
Invalid Action: The action s3:HeadObject does not exist. Did you mean s3:GetObject? The API called HeadObject authorizes against the IAM action s3:GetObject